# Update Junction Table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class for Developers, class for Applications.  With Fluent API I've had EF create a junction table with:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Developer>()
            .HasMany<Application>(d => d.Applications)
            .WithMany(a => a.Developers)
            .Map(ad =>
            {
                ad.MapLeftKey("DeveloperRefId");
                ad.MapRightKey("ApplicationRefId");
                ad.ToTable("DeveloperApplication");
            });
```

When inserting new Applications, EF writes to the junction table as expected.

**However, when I update, nothing is getting updated in the junction table.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!** One thing I've tried is that I've tried to attach each developer, and what it will do is create a new ID for application and then insert into the junction table appropriately, but how to get it to update instead?

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Application application)
        {
                using (var db = new ApplicationLibraryContext())
                {
                    // see if update is required
                    var entity = db.Applications.Find(app.Id);
                    if (entity != null)
                    {
                        db.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(app);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return Ok(app.Id);
                    }

                   // else insert new 
                   // . . . 
         }
```

*Additional Information*

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Developer> Developers { get; set; }
}

public class Developer : IModificationHistory
{
    public int DeveloperId { get; set; }
    public string DeveloperName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do `entity` and `application` come from and how are they populated?

Comment: This is a web-api controller.  An application is passed to it "application", and is properly filled with all developers.  entity comes from:  var entity = db.Applications.Find(application.Id);

Comment: Whenever I need many-to-many I never mention the junction table. Entity Framework recognizes the many-to-many from the use of ICollection<Developer> and ICollection<Application> and creates the junction table anyway. This works fine, the table is always updated and I don't need it when asking for "Several Developers with some of their Applications" or vice versa. What happens if you leave the junction table out completely? Why would you need it?